# Sort a list in c# based on exact match/partial match

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of elements list

> 1) taymril 6.5% inmatro
>   2) taymril 11.5% tometo
>   3) taymril 1.5% romeo

The input string is, for example, taymril 1.5% romeo. How do I sort the above list (15-20 elements but I have written only three as an example) based on a match with the input string? how do I do this in a generic way for all input strings and all elements in the database? any idea?

Comment: You could use a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to calculate _dissimilarity_, then use `list = list.OrderBy(s => GetLevenshteinDistance(input, s)).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listString = new List<string>();
            listString.Add("taymril 6.5% inmatro");
            listString.Add("taymril 11.5% tometo");
            listString.Add("taymril 1.5% romeo");

            var list = listString.OrderBy(x => x);
              //or
            var listd = listString.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```